# How to move the whole block of {align*} to the left?

Tags: equations, positioning, amsmath

I use `{align*}` a lot, it seems that the block of `{align*}` are automatically centered. How could I move the block to the left margin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `flalign` option to get left

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}% this is centered
a &=b
\end{align*}
%
\begin{flalign*}
a &=b &% Need this tailing alignment char to get all the way left
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool... But I want some blocks to be on the left, some blocks to be in the center...

Comment: Ok, have updated the solution.