# How to left align any LaTeX code?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move the whole block of {align*} to the left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25268/how-to-move-the-whole-block-of-align-to-the-left)

How can I make this simple code to appear left aligned?

```
\begin{align} \frac{cos2A}{1-sin2A}=cot(45^o-A) \end{align}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: In addition to following Peter Grill's link, I'd also suggest entering the equation as follows: `\begin{equation} \frac{\cos 2A}{1-\sin 2A} = \cot(45^\circ-A) \end{equation}`.

Comment: Please confirm if this is a duplicate of Peter Grill's link; if so, that's great! If not, let us know how it is different