# How to move the whole block of {align*} to some spaces towards the left?

Tags: math-mode

I use `{align*}` a lot, it seems that the block of `{align*}` are automatically centered. How could I shift the block towards the left margin to some spaces? (I.e. not all the way to left, but just some spaces towards left.)

It is different from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25268/how-to-move-the-whole-block-of-align-to-the-left).

Comment: It's not really clear why you want this in the first place. Can you explain?

Comment: I need it because after the second text (heading) the use of align* doesn't properly centers the equation or it seems that equation is way too right. That's why I want to shift it a little left of my choice.

Comment: An example would be useful.

Comment: \textbf{Detection Problem}
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{H}_0: \textbf{y}[n]&=\textbf{w}[n], && n=1, \cdots N,\\
\end{align*}
where; \textbf{x}[n] represents primary user signal, \textbf{w}[n] is additive zero-mean.
\\~\\

\textbf{For simplicity of notation}
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{H}_0: \textbf{y}&=\textbf{w}, \hspace*{2.0cm}\\
 \mathcal{H}_1: \textbf{y}&=\textbf{x}+\textbf{w}. 
\end{align*}
\\~\\
where; $\textbf{w} \sim \mathcal{N}(\textbf{0}, \sigma^2\textbf{I} )$
\end{frame}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add additional space to the right hand side of the equation via `\hspace`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent
This is centered:
\begin{align*}
a &=b
\end{align*}
Adding a \verb|\hspace{2.0cm}| to right hand side:
\begin{align*}
a &=b \hspace{2.0cm}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: note that you can also add negative space before the equation instead of adding after, also if there are several lines you need to do it for each line.

Answer (score 7):

`mathtools` provides `\MoveEqLeft[<number>]` for this. Put the macro at the end of first line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
     x &=  x_ot+v_ot+\frac{1}{2}at^2 \\
    v &= v_ot+at \\
    v^2 &= v_o^2+2a \Delta x
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align*}
     x &=  x_ot+v_ot+\frac{1}{2}at^2 \MoveEqLeft[1]\\
    v &= v_ot+at \\
    v^2 &= v_o^2+2a \Delta x
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's probably better to use `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` in the first of the three rows.

Comment: That is a bit misuse of `\MoveEqLeft`, though I do not understand the OPs intention with the question.